# Swift SpriteKit: Background speeds up when I tap?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Ive been working on this game, and have a ground for my sprite to walk on, but whenever I tap for the sprite to jump, the ground speeds up gradually with every tap to a ridiculous pace and I don't want it to do this. How do I fix it?

Here is my code for the ground:

class MCTGround: SKSpriteNode {

```
let numberOfSegments = 21
let colorOne = UIColor(red: 88.0/255.0, green: 148.0/255.0, blue:87.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let colorTwo = UIColor(red: 120.0/255.0, green: 195.0/255.0, blue: 118.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.brownColor(), size: CGSizeMake(size.width * 2, size.height))
    anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)

    for var i = 0; i < numberOfSegments; i++ {
        var segmentColor: UIColor!

        if i  % 2 == 0 {
            segmentColor = colorOne

        } else {
            segmentColor = colorTwo
        }
        let segment = SKSpriteNode(color: segmentColor, size: CGSizeMake(self.size.width / CGFloat(numberOfSegments), self.size.height))
        segment.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)
        segment.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(i) * segment.size.width, 0)
        addChild(segment)

    }

 }

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }

func start() {
    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-frame.size.width / 2, y: 0, duration: 1.0)
    let resetPosition = SKAction.moveToX(0, duration: 0)
    let moveSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveLeft, resetPosition])

        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveSequence))



    }


}
```

Edit: My touchesBegan func:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    jumpPlayer()
    movingGround.start()



    fruitGenerator.startGeneratingFruitEvery(3)


let frames = [
    SKTexture(imageNamed: "koala_idle"),
    SKTexture(imageNamed: "koala_walk01"),
    SKTexture(imageNamed: "koala_walk02"),


]

let duration = 1.5 + drand48() * 1.0

let move = SKAction.animateWithTextures(frames, timePerFrame:0.10)
let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(duration)
let rest = SKAction.setTexture(frames[0])
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([move, rest])

player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence))







}
```

Comment: What's in your touches method in your scene

Comment: Added it in as an edit

Answer (score 0):

It's because you add an additional action to the background every time. Just do:

```
var hasBegun = false
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    jumpPlayer()
    if !hasBegun {
        hasBegun = true
        movingGround.start()
        fruitGenerator.startGeneratingFruitEvery(3)
    }

    ...
```

or any other method of only running those "start"-type methods once.